# How to make a button keep moving every click on it?

Tags: javascript, html

I've made this code to make the button keep moving to the left every click on it .. but it moves one time only and stop .. please help me to find the error

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <style>
    #myBtn {
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <button type="button" id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Set left position to 
    100 px</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myBtn").style.left = "100px";
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you assign the same value: `left = "100px"` each time

Comment: Ha! haven't seen that for a long time :) Don't use html4, [html5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5) is the bomb!

Comment: How ? Sorry i'm an entry level

Answer (score 3):

```js
function myFunction() {

  var currentLeft = parseInt(document.getElementById("myBtn").style.left) || 0;

  document.getElementById("myBtn").style.left = currentLeft + 100 + "px";
}
```

```css
#myBtn {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <button type="button" id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Set left position to 
        100 px</button>


</body>

</html>
```

get the current left position, increase by 100 and assign to element.

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").style.left = parseInt(document.getElementById("myBtn").style.left) + 100 + "px";
```

Comment: didn't work ): could you write the complete code please

Comment: see the snippet

Comment: this is what I was planning to post but you @azad already posted it before me

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just setting it to a static value of 100px. You should make it such that on every click this value gradually keeps decreasing or increasing like:

```
1 click - 100px
2 click - 80px
3 click - 60px
```

and so on....

I dont have much html knowledge but i figured this much.

Comment: I can't get what do you mean .. could you write the complete code please

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out where is your button each time you click:

```
var rec = document.getElementById("myBtn").getBoundingClientRect();
document.getElementById("myBtn").style.left = 100+rec.left+'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <style>
    #myBtn {
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <button type="button" id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Set left position to 
    100 px</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {

      var position = document.getElementById("myBtn").style.left ? document.getElementById("myBtn").style.left : "0px";
      position = parseInt(position.substring(0, position.length - 2)); 
      document.getElementById("myBtn").style.left = position + 100 + "px";
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```